# Array of classes which create instances

Tags: java, arrays, instance

having `Obj` class  which in his constructor has `System.out.println("Hello world!") ;`

I create an array of this class using - `Obj[] objArray = new Obj[10] ;`  and nothing printed ,  means - no instance of `Obj` has been called   . Is there any way to create such array ,but with instances , beyond create them in for loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since you want to know a way apart from using a for loop, you can do this: -

```
Obj[] objArray = {new Obj(), new Obj(), new Obj()};
```

What happens here is, you are initializing your array reference directly with array elements. 
Now the type of actual array object is inferred from type of array reference on the LHS.

So, with that declaration, an array of size 3 (in the above case) is created, with each index in the array initialized with the `instance` of `Obj` class in the given order.

---

A better way that I would suggest is to use an `ArrayList`, in which case, you have `double-braces initialization` to initialize your `List` without for loop. And plus with an added advantage that you can anytime add new elements to it. As it `dynamically increasing` array.

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>() {
    {
        add(new Obj());
        add(new Obj());
        add(new Obj());
    }
};  // Note the semi-colon here.

list.add(new Obj());  // Add another element here.
```

Comment: @Downvoter.. Any reason for downvote? That too on this answer?? Strange. Didn't you see that OP mentioned, he didn't wanted a for-loop?

Comment: I saw that you have 16k rep and i thought that you can give a better answer on this ... edit your answer to remove my downvote

Comment: @memosdp. Yeah actually my previous answer really lacked good explanation. Thanks :)

Comment: This is how some students expecting more from their teachers. You are welcome! :)

Comment: Nah just a kick or better poke to let them know that you expecting more from them. :P

Answer (score 3):

Answers so far are good and helpful. I'm here just to remind you about

```
Obj[] objArray = new Obj[10];
Arrays.fill(objArray, new Obj());
```

Though, this will only assign one reference (to a new Obj()) to all of the elements of array.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `Obj[] objArray = new Obj[10] ;`
You only create an array of references to point to the actual 'Obj` object.

But in your case the actual Obj object is never created.

```
for (int i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
objArray[i] = new Obj();
}
```

Doing above will print the desired.

Finally do `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(objArray))` to print `toString()` of all the `Obj`

Comment: OP don't want to use a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

`Obj[] objArray = new Obj[10] ;` just creates an array capable of holding 10 Objs.  To place Objs into the array you need to either use Rohit's approach or write a simple `for` loop to initialize the array entries one at a time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    objArray[i] = new Obj();
}
```

Or, without a for loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    objArray[i] = new Obj();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: OP don't want to use a for loop. Please see that,

Comment: I'd want to know for what reason he doesn't want a for loop.

Comment: (He can always use a while instead.)

Comment: @HotLicks.. Ah! it's not that he don't want to use it. It's like, he want to know whether there is another way or not, that don't require a for loop.

Comment: Well, one could always do `objArray[0] = ...; objArray[1] = ...; objArray[2]= ...; ...` -- which is essentially what happens with `{new Obj(), new Obj(), new Obj()};` under the covers.

Comment: Yeah that's also a way. I can't deny it.

Comment: Then there was the "Schema" language (not relation to Scheme) used internally in the iSeries "Old MI Translator".  In that you'd code the for loop, but it expanded automatically into the sequence of assignments -- you had to actually take steps to PREVENT loop unrolling when you didn't want it.  Very useful for its purpose -- translating conceptual operations into machine instructions.

Comment: Ok, now it's getting over my head.